# JQ - Fetch all the paths in json including "null" values

Tags: json, path, null, jq

I have a json file in which I wish to retrieve all the paths of all the keys.
I have been using JQ, however, it does not show the paths which have null as their values. What am I missing here?

Json :

```
{
    "Root": [
        {
            "id1": "val",
            "id2": "val",
            "id3": null,
            "id4": 1,
            "id5": null,
            "id6": "val",
            "id7": {
                "id8": "val",
                "id9": "val",
                "id10": null,
                "id11": "val"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```
jq -r 'paths(scalars)  as $p  | [ ( [ $p[] | tostring ]  | join(".") ), ( getpath($p) | tojson )] | join(": ")' test_data.json
```

Output is as shown as

```
{
    "Root": [
        {
            "id1": "val",
            "id2": "val",
            "id3": null,
            "id4": 1,
            "id5": null,
            "id6": "val",
            "id7": {
                "id8": "val",
                "id9": "val",
                "id10": null,
                "id11": "val"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to see path of the all nodes including those which have null as their value.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is covered in the [jq FAQ](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ), wherein the following def for a more inclusive version of `paths` is given:

```
def allpaths:
  def conditional_recurse(f):  def r: ., (select(.!=null) | f | r); r;
  path(conditional_recurse(.[]?)) | select(length > 0);
```

The corresponding version of `paths/1` would be:

```
def allpaths(filter):
  allpaths as $p | getpath($p) as $v | select($v | filter) | $p;
```